# Изменение HTML кода без перезагрузки приложения ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Пишу на сайт на ASP.Net Core. При внесении изменений в HTML код, чтобы увидеть изменения на странице , приходится перезагружать проект в VS. При изменении css, можно просто перезагрузить страницу и все, есть какой-то выход для HTML?

Comment: Вынести шаблоны HTML отдельно и сделать так, чтобы программа перечитывала шаблон для каждого запроса.

Comment: Вынести куда? Я так понял в папку wwwroot и там уже менять html

Comment: [Вот](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77322/update-net-website-without-reloading) еще вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте проект не через F5 (или запуск на панели инструментов), а через Обозреватель решений, щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши на любом файле cshtml и выбрав пункт меню "Просмотреть в браузере (Ваш браузер по умолчанию)". После изменения html-кода достаточно будет обновить страницу сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Установить пакет **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**
А в **program.cs** добавить

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```